# mongoDb: aggregate document references to subgroups

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've a set of BSON documents in a mongoDb collection which I want to process according to form cascading sub-documents. There are thousand of duplicate `id`'s only to be differentiated by timestamps and documents with type `subsystem`-> `component` -> `subcomponent`; and they should be attached to each other based on `source`. This is a sample I currently have:

```
[{
    "id": 1001,
    "type": "subsystem",
    "time": 1454767739,
    "payload": {
        "key": "..."
    }
},
{
    "id": 1001,
    "type": "subsystem",
    "time": 1454767539,
    "payload": {
        "key": "..."
    }
},
{
    "id": 2001,
    "type": "component",
    "time": 1454767778,
    "source": 1001,
    "payload": {
        "key": "..."
    }
},
{
    "id": 5002,
    "type": "subcomponent",
    "time": 1454767779,
    "source": 2001,
    "payload": {
        "key": "..."
    }
},
{
    "id": 5003,
    "type": "subcomponent",
    "time": 1454767798,
    "source": 2001,
    "payload": {
        "key": "..."
    }
}]
```

And what am I trying to do is this:

1. match all elements with a timestamp lower than a `maxTime` value
2. group all elements by (unique) id, but only use the newest value (`$max: $time`) for `$$ROOT` (every `id` is unique now)
3. group all by attribute `source` as a array to the element with that `id` (or `_id`)

I've achieved 1.) and 2.) already have this group:

```
[{
    "_id": 1001,
    "reftime": 1454767739,
    "element": [
        {
            "id": 1001,
            "type": "subsystem",
            "time": 1454767739,
            "payload": {
                "key": "..."
            }
        }
    ]

},
{
    "_id": 2001,
    "reftime": 1454767778,
    "element": [
        {
            "id": 2001,
            "type": "component",
            "time": 1454767778,
            "source": 1001,
            "payload": {
                "key": "..."
            }
        }

    ]
},
{
    "_id": 5002,
    "reftime": 1454767779,
    "element": [
        {
            "id": 5002,
            "type": "subcomponent",
            "time": 1454767779,
            "source": 2001,
            "payload": {
                "key": "..."
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": 5003,
    "reftime": 1454767798,
    "element": [
        {
            "id": 5003,
            "type": "subcomponent",
            "time": 1454767798,
            "source": 2001,
            "payload": {
                "key": "..."
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

But what I want is the elements to be structured according to their links in the `source` value. So it would look something like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1001,
    "reftime": 1454767739,
    "element": [
        {
            "id": 1001,
            "type": "subsystem",
            "time": 1454767739,
            "payload": {
                "key": "..."
            }
        }
    ],
    "attached": [
        {
            "_id": 2001,
            "reftime": 1454767778,
            "element": [
                {
                    "id": 2001,
                    "type": "component",
                    "time": 1454767778,
                    "source": 1001,
                    "payload": {
                        "key": "..."
                    }
                }
            ],
            "attached": [
                {
                    "_id": 5002,
                    "reftime": 1454767779,
                    "element": [
                        {
                            "id": 5002,
                            "type": "subcomponent",
                            "time": 1454767779,
                            "source": 2001,
                            "payload": {
                                "key": "..."
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": 5003,
                    "reftime": 1454767798,
                    "element": [
                        {
                            "id": 5003,
                            "type": "subcomponent",
                            "time": 1454767798,
                            "source": 2001,
                            "payload": {
                                "key": "..."
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }                

            ]
        }        
    ]

}
```

Is this possible? I'm struggling to form a group with everything that has a `source` and combine this with the group from sample 2.). Or if that would help, I could introduce a `source: 0`? for every `subsystem` and group by that under a single root element?

Any ideas or insights? I'm currently stuck at this point. Thank you!